# CSS: Aligning three buttons in two rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got 3 buttons where I want to have 2 buttons horizontal to each other of same size with some spacing between them and then a third image below the 2 buttons full width.

```css
.menu-search .apply-button {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.apply-button {
  background-color: #01AAAD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-search .clear-button {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.clear-button {
  background-color: #01AAAD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-search .close-button {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.close-button {
  background-color: #01AAAD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-search">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type = "button" class="apply-button" id="btnTrustSearch" value="Aply Filters">
      <input  type = "button" class="clear-button" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input  type = "button" class="close-button close-search" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzoyf64q/5/) for the same code.

Comment: Those `<input>` fields default to text fields. You need to specify the type attribute of the field i.e. `type="button"`.

Comment: use display: inline-block to horizontally aligned your buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul, li, input{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-search ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-search ul li:first-child{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.menu-search ul li:first-child input{
  flex-basis: 45%;
}
.menu-search .button{
    background-color:#01AAAD;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
    line-height:35px;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.menu-search .close-button{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-search">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class="button apply-button" id="btnTrustSearch" value="Aply Filters">
      <input class="button clear-button" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
    </li>
    <li><input class="button close-button close-search" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your choice comes down to either floating the elements or using inline-block. I have modified freestock.tk's solution to use inline-block. Notice that when you use inline-block, the whitespace in your HTML becomes significant. So, if you add a newline character after the first input element, the first two buttons would appear one below the other.

Your choice will ultimately come down to the differences between floats and inline-blocks and which characteristics of each you need. More info on when to choose inline-block [here](http://vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/)

- Use inline-blocks — when you need more control over the vertical alignment or horizontal positioning of elements.
- Use floats — when you need other elements to flow around an element, support older versions of IE, or don’t want to deal with the horizontal whitespace issue.

Also important to this solution is the CSS3 box-sizing property [Learn more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```css
.menu-search {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.button {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: Red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one,
.two {
  width: 40%;
}

.three {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-search">
  <input class="one button" id="btnTrustSearch" value="One"><input class="two button" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Two">
  <input class="three button" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Three">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu-search .apply-button {
  width: 45%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #01AAAD;
}
.menu-search .clear-button {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  clear: right;
}
.clear-button {
  background-color: #01AAAD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-search .close-button {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.close-button {
  background-color: #01AAAD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu-search {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto auto;
```

```html
<div class="menu-search">
      <input class="apply-button" id="btnTrustSearch" value="Aply Filters">
      <input class="clear-button" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
      <input class="close-button close-search" id="btnTrustClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS :

```
.menu-search .apply-button{
    width:45%;
    margin-right:10%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
    line-height:35px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
}

.apply-button{ 
     background-color:#01AAAD;
     color:#FFFFFF;
 }


.menu-search .clear-button{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.clear-button{ 
     background-color:#01AAAD;
     color:#FFFFFF;
 }


.menu-search .close-button{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.close-button{ 
     background-color:#01AAAD;
     color:#FFFFFF;
 }
```